# VSCode SSH Remote useLocalServer is true while it should be false

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

For some reason, when I try to connect to a specific host in VSCode, I see that `"remote.SSH.useLocalServer"` is set to `true`, while the local user settings JSON has it explicitly set to `false`.
This makes the remote crash and unable to connect for this specific host, while other hosts are working fine.

The host worked just fine before I added `"remote.SSH.useLocalServer":true` in the host's `~/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json` and reloaded the window. Since then, when I try to connect to the host it always fails with an error, even after I manually deleted the `"remote.SSH.useLocalServer":true` line from the server using nano.

I suspect this is because VSCode stashed the host settings somewhere locally, and now is unable to access the host because of the settings.

How do I force the remote extension to respect the user settings?
[image: Remote SSH Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the cached configuration of the server, to fix it edit the `AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedConfigurations\user\*REMOTENAME*\configuration.json`.